# Not able to set action bar title on back press in Android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am currently working on an Android app. It has a navigation drawer and a few fragments. I want the actionbar title to change depending on the fragment. I have managed to do this. But the problem is when I press the back button the setTitle() method is executed and the title is changed but it does not reflect on the action bar visibly.

EDIT: I found out that the problem was with the navigation drawer opening and closing. So I removed the changing title part from the ondraweropened() and ondrawerclosed(). It solved the current problem. But I want the name to change on opening and retain the current fragment name on closing. Can anyone help me on that?

This is my main activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION="com.example.test.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";;
static final String SERVER_URL = "http://doylefermi.x20.in/register.php";
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
public static String acc = "";
public String msg = "";
public static String accn = "";
String SENDER_ID = "1019787135827";
static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
TextView mDisplay;
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
SharedPreferences prefs;
Context context;
String regid="";
String email="";
String title="";
String name="";
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String[] navMenuTitles;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader= new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild=new  HashMap<String,List<String>>();
private LinearLayout mDrawerLinear;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    setupActionBar();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment f=new DestinationsFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, f).commit();
    mDrawerLinear= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_bar);
    mDrawerLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.tourist_list);
    gcmcheck();

    listDataHeader.add(navMenuTitles[0]);
    listDataHeader.add(navMenuTitles[1]);
    listDataHeader.add(navMenuTitles[2]);
    listDataHeader.add(navMenuTitles[3]);
    listDataHeader.add(navMenuTitles[4]);
    List<String> dest=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> attr=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> spl=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> fest=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> abtus=new ArrayList<String>();
    attr.add("Water World");
    attr.add("Temples");
    attr.add("Arts & Crafts");
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), dest); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), attr);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), spl);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), fest); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), abtus);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_bar);
    mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }


        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            title=getTitle().toString();
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.action_bar_title1);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    listAdapter=new ExpandableListAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listDataChild);
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener(){
        @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent,View v,int groupPosition,long id){
            if(groupPosition!=1)
            {
                displayView(groupPosition,groupPosition);
                return false;
            }
            else
                 return false;

        }
    });
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            displayView(groupPosition,childPosition);
    return false;
        }
    });




}
private void displayView(int group,int position ) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (group) {
        case 0: fragment=new DestinationsFragment();title="Destinations";break;
        case 1: switch(position){

                    case 0:fragment=new WaterWorldFragment();title="Water World";break;
                    case 1:fragment=new TemplesFragment();title="Temples";break;
                    case 2:fragment=new ArtsCraftsFragment();title="Arts & Crafts";break;
        }
            break;
        case 2: fragment=new SpecialInterestFragment();title="Special Interest";
            break;
        case 3: fragment=new FestivalsFragment();title="Festivals";
            break;
        case 4: fragment=new AboutUsFragment();title="About Us";
            break;

        default: break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction;
        transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).commit();
        expListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        expListView.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);

    } else {

        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT))
    {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater m=getMenuInflater();
    m.inflate(R.menu.menu_home,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLinear);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void setupActionBar(){
    //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xffff5253));


}

private void gcmcheck()
{



   Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();

    acc= accounts[1].name;
    accn=acc.substring(0, acc.indexOf('@'));
    name=accn;
    email=acc;

    context = getApplicationContext();
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    regid = getRegistrationId(context);

    if (regid=="") {    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registering device...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        registerInBackground();
                    }
    //else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

}

private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
    // app version.
    return registrationId;
}

private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
    // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
    // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
    return getSharedPreferences(HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
private void registerInBackground() {

    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                // is using accounts.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
            final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
            final int BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS = 2000;
            final Random random = new Random();
            Log.i(TAG, "registering device (regId = " + regid + ")");
            String serverUrl = SERVER_URL;
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("regId", regid);
            params.put("name",name);
            params.put("email",email);


            long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
            // Once GCM returns a registration id, we need to register on our server
            // As the server might be down, we will retry it a couple
            // times.
            for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to register");
                try {
                    post(serverUrl, params);
                    // displayMessage(context, "Registered");
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Here we are simplifying and retrying on any error; in a real
                    // application, it should retry only on unrecoverable errors
                    // (like HTTP error code 503).
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register on attempt " + i + ":" + e);
                    if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping for " + backoff + " ms before retry");
                        Thread.sleep(backoff);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                        Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted: abort remaining retries!");
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        return;
                    }
                    // increase backoff exponentially
                    backoff *= 2;
                }
            }
            //  String message = context.getString(R.string.server_register_error,
            //        MAX_ATTEMPTS);
            //CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);

        }
        private  void post(String endpoint, Map<String, String> params)throws IOException{
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(endpoint);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + endpoint);
            }
            StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
            // constructs the POST body using the parameters
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
                bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                        .append(param.getValue());
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    bodyBuilder.append('&');
                }
            }
            String body = bodyBuilder.toString();
            Log.v(TAG, "Posting '" + body+ "' to " + url);
            byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                Log.e("URL", "> " + url);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                // post the request
                OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
                out.write(bytes);
                out.close();
                // handle the response
                int status = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (status != 200) {
                    throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
                }
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_gcm_broadcast_receiver);
        }


    }.execute(null, null, null);}

private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    //int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    // Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    //  editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

This is one of the fragments:-

```
public class DestinationsFragment extends Fragment {
    ViewPager viewPager;

public class DestinationsFragment extends Fragment implements             View.OnClickListener {

private TypedArray Icons;

PagerAdapter adapter;
String[] rank;
String[] country;
String[] population;
int[] flag;
public DestinationsFragment(){

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_5, container, false);

    Icons= getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_5, container, false);
    Button button1;
    rank = new String[] { "Heading1", "Heading2", "Heading3", "Heading4", "Heading5", "Heading6", "Heading7", "Heading8", "Heading9", "Heading10" };

    country = new String[] { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3",
            "Text4", "Text5", "Text6", "Text7", "Text8",
            "Text9", "Text10" };

    population = new String[] { "Subtext1", "Subtext2",
            "Subtext3", "Subtext4", "Subtext5", "Subtext6",
            "Subtext7", "Subtext8", "Subtext9", "Subtext10" };

    flag = new int[] { R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher };

    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    //viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    //adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(DestinationsFragment.this, rank, country, population, flag);
    //adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(buildAdapter());

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.dest);
}
private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return(new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), rank, country, population, flag));
}

    population = new String[] { "Subtext1", "Subtext2",
            "Subtext3", "Subtext4", "Subtext5", "Subtext6",
            "Subtext7", "Subtext8", "Subtext9", "Subtext10" };

    flag = new int[] { R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher };

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager.setPageMargin(-100);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(buildAdapter());

    button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}
private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return(new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), rank, country, population, flag));
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this !.

//on home activity

```
 public ActionBar getsupportactionbar() {
        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        return mActionBar;
    }
```

On your fragments :

```
      ActionBar mActionBar = ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).getsupportactionbar();
if(mActionBar !=null)
    mActionBar .setTitle(R.string.dest);
```

or may be you need to settitle on OnactivityCreated.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.

Comment: anyways thanks for the advice i  havent tried it out yet though ill upvote if it works